# Disable alignment on a 64-bit structure

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to align my structure and make it as small as possible using bit fields. I have to send this data back to a client, which will examine the fields to set a few data members.
The size of the structure is indeed the same, but when I set members it does not work at all.
Here's some example code:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct PW_INFO
{
    char hash[16]; //Does not matter
    uint32_t number; //Does not matter
    uint32_t salt_id : 30; //Position: 0 bits
    uint32_t enc_level : 7; //Position: 30 bits
    uint32_t delta : 27; //Position: 37 bits
}; //Total size: 28 bytes
#pragma pack(pop)

void int64shrl(uint64_t& base, uint32_t to_shift, uint32_t position)
{
    uint64_t res = static_cast<uint64_t>(to_shift);
    res = Int64ShllMod32(res, position);
    base |= res;
}

int32_t main()
{
    std::cout << "Size of PW_INFO: " << sizeof(PW_INFO) << "\n"; //Returns 28 as expected (16 + sizeof(uint32_t) + 8)
    PW_INFO pw = { "abc123", 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    pw.enc_level = 105;

    uint64_t base{ 0 };
    &base; //debug purposes
    int64shrl(base, 103, 30);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's where it gets weird: setting the "salt_id" field (which is 30 bits into the bitfield) will yield the following result in memory:

```
0x003FFB8C  61 62 63 31 32 33 00 00  abc123..
0x003FFB94  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........
0x003FFB9C  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........
0x003FFBA4  69 00 00 00              i...
(Only the last 8 bytes are of concern since they represent the bit field.)
```

But, Int64ShllMod32 returns a correct result (the remote client undersands it perfectly):

```
0x003FFB7C  00 00 00 c0 19 00 00 00  ...À....
```

I'm guessing it has to do with alignment, if so how would I completely get rid of it? It seems even if the size is correct, it will try to align it (1 byte boundary as the #pragma directive suggests).

More information:
I use Visual Studio 2015 and its compiler. 
I am not trying to write those in a different format, the reason I'm asking this is that I do NOT want to use my own format. They are reading from 64 bit bitfields everywhere, I don't have access to the source code but I see a lot of calls to Int64ShrlMod32 (from what I read, this is what the compiler produces when dealing with 8 byte structures). 
The actual bitfield starts at "salt_id". 30 + 7 + 27 = 64 bits, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: This is ABI & architecture specific (and probably also compiler specific). So please edit your question to explain which ABI, compiler & architecture are you coding for. Also explain why you need to pack such data please (and more generally motivate your question). BTW, on most current computers, packing data would decrease performance. So **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: Most compilers will **not** split a 7-bit field between two different ints.

Comment: There are not 37 bits in a 32-bit int

Comment: If the client wants data in a specific format then the most robust thing to do is write data in that format exactly; not use packed structs and bitfields

Comment: You are going through all this trouble to save 1-4 Bytes?

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion, I've edited my question, hopefully it answers your interrogations now. I don't have access to the application and it is pretty old, but they are using 64-bit structures for quite a lot of things, and I highly doubt they call Int64Shrl all the time

Comment: GCC packs the bitfields as you expected, when setting an alignment of 1, otherwise it doesn't. This is per standard: "*Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. ... Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others. ...*" As already suggested in the comment, the best approach is not to rely on this behavior and do the work yourself. I'm not good enough in C++ to post it as an answer, but I've made a working C++11 sample [here](http://pastebin.com/izXkL2ca). Don't use it in production code! I'm not fluent/confident enough in C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort! I really appreciate it. It doesn't really solve what I'm trying to accomplish though, but the intention matters and I sure am thankful (that did make me learn a thing or two about bitfields). :)